# C#: could generic type specify a new(type) as constrait?

Tags: c#, generics, types, constraints, new-operator

I've got this code snippet under vs2017 and .netstandard2.0 csproj:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public Foo(int i)
        {
            _i = i;
        }

        private int _i;
    }

    public class Bar<T>
    where T : Foo, new(), new(int) // error
    {
        public T Create()
        {
            return new T(8); // error 
        }
    }
```

It doesn't compile, I googled and found adding this new(int) should work, but actually doesn't. How to make it work? Some solutions from internet involves creating a very complex interface+factory methods, but my usage request is just as simple as this, is it really needed to use interface+factory method for "Foo" instance creation in a generic type Bar that use it?

Is there a way to make my code work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `new()` constraint is all about enforcing the existence of a *parameter-less* constructor on the specified type. Currently, the language doesn't offer anything like your `new(int)` syntax

Comment: "Is there a generic constructor with parameter constraint in C#?", "C# generic methods, type parameters in new() constructor constraint" <= guess what is this

Comment: "I googled and found adding this new(int) should work, but actually doesn't." Well, whatever you googled is wrong. You may have stumbled onto a discussion of a hypothetical new feature. Passing a `Func<int, T>` isn't *that* complicated.

Comment: There is no such [constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) as `new(int)`

Comment: Can you say where MS states `new(int)` should work? I doubt it should.

Comment: "is it really needed to use interface+factory method for "Foo" instance creation in a generic type Bar that use it" If you want to have a common way to instantiate different types of objects, you won´t come around factories.